# run piconv within perl script for batch conversion

Tags: windows, batch, perl

I am trying to convert a set of Windows 10 files in a directory from ANSI to UTF-8. I have found the following command that works in a command prompt for a single file if the command is run from the folder where the source file exists:

```
piconv -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 < SOURCE_File.txt > TARGET_File.txt
```

However, I need some way of doing this for ALL files in a chosen folder. I thought I could use perl with the command:

```
my $Test=system("piconv","-f", "windows-1252", "-t", "UTF-8"," < $SOURCE_File > ","$TARGET_File");
```

where $SOURCE_File and $TARGET_File will, in general, contain the full paths of the files.

BUT, this does no work! I get errors such as Invalid argument or can't open file.

Does anyone know how to put the piconv command in a perl script. I can set up the looping for each file in a given directory I just cannot work out the piconv command that converts each file.

Many thanks

Gauss76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all arguments of `piconv` in a single string:

```
system("piconv -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 $SOURCE_File >$TARGET_File");
```

Comment: OK, it seems as though I have missed the obvious, AGAIN! Many thanks Toto for your help.

Comment: @gauss76: You're welcome, glad it helps.